# Remotely Monitoring RDP Certificate

Tags: ssl-certificate, openssl, rdp

We use OpenSSL on a CentOS 6 server to monitor the certificate on servers for RDP.

To do this we use:

`openssl s_client -connect SERVER01:3389 -prexit`

This has worked flawlessly until 4 days ago, when it suddenly stops showing that a cert is used and instead shows the following for a single server:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
140439032170136:error:140790E5:SSL routines:ssl23_write:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:177:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 305 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID:
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key:
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1539710511
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 305 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID:
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key:
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1539710511
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

I have seen that older versions of OpenSSL caused this error, but since the version hasn't change (1.0.1e) and it was working, I cannot see what is wrong.

I've also tried resetting the server's RDP cert, but again no change.

Comment: So RDP TLS connections are working, the issue is the OpenSSL test is failing?

Comment: That is correct. Suddenly after years of working, is stopped for this one server. Others work as per normal. The openssl server can access it so it's not firewall, and I have tested from other systems and get same result.

Comment: I ran into the same issue a few days ago. Was nobody able to come up with a solution?

Comment: It sounds your RDP isn't listening over SSL anymore. I think you're looking to openssl, but the problem is at the RDP side

Comment: What happens when you execute the openssl command on another valid HTTPS IP:port?

Comment: @surfingonthenet Openssl is working as expected. The issue started after a dist upgrade to 20.04 LTS. I found this https://github.com/GoSecure/pyrdp where I currently try to extract all the necessary bits from pyrdp-clonecert.py because this is working. I just dont understand why it ever worked in the first place, as I have found on https://corelight.blog/2020/05/13/analyzing-encrypted-rdp-connections/ that there is a protocoll called X.224 that needs to be done before TLS is even initiating. So in my understanding this should have never worked in the first place? Or openssl removed something?

Comment: @Daywalker, yep, that sounds it's not working over SSL/TLS. If you execute the same openssl command to another service with no SSL (i.e. to port 80), you'll get a similar result

Comment: @surfingonthenet But I'd still like to know why it was working before...
Anybody here who is good at studying a changelogs from Openssl (included in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS)?

Comment: I'd check cipher suite or TLS version default changes between 18.04 and 20.04. The newer OS might default to a more secure set that doesn't have any matches with what is enabled on the Windows server. You might also be able to see the mismatch in a packet capture during the TLS handshake.

Comment: Can you make sure that there is no deep inspection firewall in between which may stop the traffic?